# Mysql calculate timediffrence between rows based on grouping

Tags: mysql

Hi im trying to write a query that calculates the time diffrence for every row in a specific grouping (In this case "skopor") as you can see in the image:

[What i trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x9yr.png)

Im using this code but it doesnt work, it give the last stamp before a new group (Skopor) a negative number.

```
SELECT A.id, A.Skopor, A.Timestamp, (B.Timestamp - A.Timestamp) AS timediffFROM Skopor A INNER JOIN Skopor B ON B.id = (A.id + 1) ORDER BY A.Skopor ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can following functions in mysql to achieve this -

1. lag
2. timestampdiff
3. sec_to_time

Main query -

```
select t.*, 
sec_to_time(timestampdiff(second,ifnull(lag(t.time_1) over 
(partition by skopor order by id), t.time_1), t.time_1)) as time_diff 
from tab_time_diff t;
```

Here is the db [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9bb0fe05b5625018c3faa6dc96bbe43)